# Return one SQL row per product with price and latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not a SQL guy, I have used it in the past and rarely have an issue that cant be solved by google... however this time I need to ask the Community.

I have a database with a table called 'Transactions' it has data like this:

```
ProdNo    | Price | TransactionDate | PurchasedBy | etc.....
----------------------------------------------------------
3STRFLEX  | 13.02 | 20162911        | AWC         | .....
3STRFLEX  | 15.02 | 20162011        | DWC         | .....
3STRFLEX  | 15.02 | 20160101        | AWC         | .....
AFTV2     | 35.49 | 20162708        | AWC         | .....
AFTV2     | 29.99 | 20160106        | DWC         | .....
AFTV2     | 29.99 | 20160205        | AWC         | .....
```

The desired output is:

```
ProdNo    | Price | TransactionDate 
-----------------------------------
3STRFLEX  | 13.02 | 20162911        
AFTV2     | 35.49 | 20162708
```

I have tried a to write this myself and I ended up with SQL like this:

```
select t.ProdNo, t.TransactionDate as 'LastPurchaseDate', t.Price
from Transactions t
inner join (
     select ProdNo, max(TransactionDate) as 'LastPurchaseDate'
     from Transactions
     WHERE Price > 0
     group by ProdNo
 ) tm on t.ProdNo = tm.ProdNo and LastPurchaseDate = tm.LastPurchaseDate
```

However in my data set this returns (cut down) which shows multiple rows per product

```
ProdNo    | LastPurchaseDate | Price
3STRFLX   | 20120924         | 0.000000
3STRFLX   | 20120924         | 22.000000
3STRFLX   | 20150623         | 0.000000
3STRFLX   | 20150623         | 1.220000
3STRFLX   | 20150623         | 1.222197
```

So to confirm: I would like 1 row per product for the latest date it was purchased regardless of the price, but I need the price in the returned data.

Thanks

Comment: This question received a down vote.  But without a comment, the OP has no way to fix/address the issue.  It also makes it hard to debate the point.  I can't see anything wrong with the question.  But perhaps with a comment I would have agreed...  As it stands I've upvoted for including sample data, expected output, original effort and a clear description of the issue.

Comment: @destination-data thank you. I don't see this issue either, perhaps I missed some rule or something though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a CTE and the ranking function `PARTITION BY`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    select t.ProdNo, t.TransactionDate as 'LastPurchaseDate', t.Price,
           rn = row_number() over (partition by ProdNo order by TransactionDate desc)
    from Transactions t
)
SELECT ProdNo, LastPurchaseDate, Price  FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: This appears to work perfectly.Thanks! I will research about CTE now so hopefully I won't need to ask again

Comment: This will return an arbitrary record if you have more then one record per `ProdNo` with the same `max(TransactionDate )`

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. What if you use:

```
select t.ProdNo, t.TransactionDate as 'LastPurchaseDate', t.Price
from Transactions t
inner join (
     select ProdNo, max(TransactionDate) as 'LastPurchaseDate'
     from Transactions
     WHERE Price > 0
     group by ProdNo
 ) tm on t.ProdNo = tm.ProdNo and t.TransactionDate= tm.LastPurchaseDate
```

Note the change in join conditions.

What happened in your query: `LastPurchaseDate = tm.LastPurchaseDate`. There is only one column called `LastPurchaseDate`, so it's equating it with itself, which is always true. So you're left with `t.ProdNo = tm.ProdNo`, since `t.ProdNo` is not unique, you get multiple records returned for each `t.ProdNo`.

Comment: Unfortunately this still returns multiple rows. Thanks for spotting that though.

Comment: @TedJames, Ah, I see, you have more then one record with the same `max(TransactionDate)`. You'll have to decide which of those records you want to select. `ROW_NUMBER()` can help, but it will return an arbitrary record.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses the [ROW_NUMBER windowed function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

My query uses a [common table expression (CTE)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to provide sample data.  When using this technique you always need a CTE, or [subquery](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx).  This is because values generated in the SELECT clause are not available to the WHERE clause.  This is a consequence of something called the [Logical Processing Order](https://destinationdata.wordpress.com/2016/01/10/the-logical-processing-order-3/).  In other words; SQL Server generates the row numbers after it has filtered the data.  CTEs/Subqueries provide you with a second WHERE clause, that is actioned after the row numbers have been generated**.

```
-- Returning the most recent record from a transaction table.
WITH SampleDate AS
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProdNo ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC) AS Rn,
            *
        FROM
            (
                VALUES                      
                    ('3STRFLEX', 13.02, '20162911', 'AWC '),
                    ('3STRFLEX', 15.02, '20162011', 'DWC '),
                    ('3STRFLEX', 15.02, '20160101', 'AWC '),
                    ('AFTV2'   , 35.49, '20162708', 'AWC '),
                    ('AFTV2'   , 29.99, '20160106', 'DWC '),
                    ('AFTV2'   , 29.99, '20160205', 'AWC ')
            ) AS x(ProdNo, Price, TransactionDate, PurchasedBy)
    )
SELECT
    *
FROM
    SampleDate
WHERE
    Rn = 1
;
```

** Actually this isn't entirely true.  It is called the *logical* order for a reason.  SQL Sever can/will exeucte your queries any way it sees fit.  But however your query is physically executed it will respect the logical order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. by using row_number().

```
             select * from 
             (
             select 
             T.ProdNo, 
             T.TransactionDate as 'LastPurchaseDate', 
             T.Price,           
             row_number() over (partition by ProdNo order by TransactionDate desc) as rnk
             from Transactions T
             )a
             where rnk='1'
```

Comment: Why `rnk='1'`? `ROW_NUMBER()` returns a `bigint`, so `rnk = 1` makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Pls Try this
--If one ProdNo has two same max TransactionDate, will return both two rows

```
select ProdNo,Price,TransactionDate from Transactions t 
where not exists (select 1 from Transactions where ProdNo=t.ProdNo and TransactionDate>t.TransactionDate)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT A.ProdNo ,Price ,A.TransactionDate,PurchasedBy 
FROM #Transactions 
JOIN 
(
SELECT ProdNo,MAX(TransactionDate) TransactionDate
FROM #Transactions 
GROUP BY ProdNo
)A ON A.TransactionDate = #Trans.TransactionDate
```